# While statement for downloading URL strings

Tags: c#, url

I would like to ask, How I can use the While statement for downloading URL?

Here's what I want to happen.
I want to check if the url from CheckBoxListItems is already exist from my ListView

There's a case that I'm adding another urls to my listbox and I don't want to download again.

if url is already exists in my listview it will skip and proceed to the next url(which is not yet downloaded).

Here's my current codes:

```
        int count = 0;
        int total = LB.CheckedItems.Count;
        string counter = string.Empty;

        using (cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            try
            {
                if (cts.IsCancellationRequested) { throw new TaskCanceledException(); }

                txtOutput.Text = string.Empty;
                Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                Parsing = true;
                Text = "Getting links information. Please wait...";

                foreach (string url in LB.CheckedItems)
                {
                    var info = await Task.Run(() => Parser.GetJsonData(url, cts.Token));
                    
                    count++;
                    counter = "( " + count + " of " + total + " )";
                    lblTotalLinks.Text = counter;
                    Text = "Parsing in progress. Please wait... " + counter;

                    AddToListView(info); //ADD DOWNLOADED STRINGS TO LISTVIEW
                }
                Text = "Parsing done. " + counter;
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
            { Text = ex.Message; }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); }
        }
        Parsing = false;
        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        cts = null;
```

//ADD TO LISTVIEW()

```
 private void AddToListView(MediaInfo info)
    {
        int count = LV.Items.Count + 1;

        var results = new List<ListViewItem> { new ListViewItem(new[]
        {
            count.ToString(),
            info.Series,
            "Episode " + info.Episode,
            info.Title,
            info.Runtime,
            info.Resolution,
            info.Category,
            info.URL, //here's what I want to check if already exists
            info.M3u8_url,
            info.FileSize,
            info.Fragments
        })};

        ListViewItem[] array = results.ToArray();

        LV.BeginUpdate();
        LV.ListViewItemSorter = null;

        LV.Items.AddRange(array);
        LV.Focus();
        LV.EndUpdate();
        Countlists();
        LV.Items[LV.Items.Count - 1].EnsureVisible();
    }
```

this is the example of what I want:

```
  string urlExists = string.Empty;

         foreach (ListViewItem item in LV.Items)
           {
              urlExists = item.SubItems[7].Text;

              foreach (string url in LB.CheckedItems)
              {
                while (url != urlExists)
                    {
               }
           }
```

Comment: Is `foreach (string url in LB.CheckedItems) { ... }` your current implementation of what you've described?  If not, that'd be about the way to do it.  Why does it need to be a `while` loop, specifically?  `foreach` or `for` would be a bit more concise loops for iterating a collection.

Comment: I'm not actually sure if while loops is better to use. But I want to skip the url if already exists in my ListviewItems from my checklistbox. So that I don't need to download again if I will add another url to listbox. It must skip and proceed to next url

Comment: `foreach`, `for`, and `while` can all be used to iterate a collection.  `for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++) { ... }` saves a couple lines over `int i = 0; while (i < collection.Count) { ... i++; }`, although if you know something about your data/requirements that we don't then something like `do { /* Consume URLs */ } while (urlWasAddedToList);` could work, too.  It sounds like the focus of your question isn't the type of loop at all but rather making `AddToListView(info);` conditional.  For that it would be helpful to see the definition of `AddToListView()` and the relevant list.

Comment: Alright I have added the codes for AddToListview
I'll try to analyze what your are saying